# How to set default props values to custom state less component in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a really simple component, called `Divider` here is the source code:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

export default class Divider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = { styles.separator } />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separator: {
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF80",
  },
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the values in `styles.separator` becomes the default values of this component, since those are the values which I am using in most cases, but in some edge cases I need to change the `marginBottom` to `16` for example.

So most case I just want to do `<Divider />`, but sometimes `<Divider marginBottom = 16 />`

What I have currently is something like this below, but obviously this doesn't work.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

export default class Divider extends React.Component {
  static defaultPropts = {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF80",
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{
        height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        marginTop: {this.props.marginTop},
        marginBottom: {this.props.marginBottom},
        backgroundColor: {this.props.backgroundColor},
      }} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after researching a bit I found out that this works.

```
import React from "react";
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

export default class Divider extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    customWidth: Dimensions.get("window").width / 2.0,
  }

  render() {
    const halfWidth = this.props.customWidth 

    return (
      <View style = { [styles.separator, {width: halfWidth}] } />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separator: {
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF80",
  },
});
```

So now whenever I use `<Divider />` its width gonna be half of the screen size, but if I dod `<Divider customWidth = { 10 }`, then it will overwrite the default value and will be 10 dp instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive your custom style by props and use them in your component style as array. When you call the props style after the component's, it will overwrite any equal style property it already has.

For example, let's say you have a component named 'Card', you can write your component like this:

```
<View style={[style.cardStyle, props.style]}>
  {props.children}
</View>
```

And call it like this `<Card style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}} />`

So it's getting all defined 'cardStyle' from it's own component, also adding the styles received by props.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

You can try something like this

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const Divider = (props) => {
      <View style = {{
        height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        marginTop: {this.props.marginTop},
        marginBottom: {this.props.marginBottom},
        backgroundColor: {this.props.backgroundColor},
      }} />
}

Divider.defaultProps = {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF80",
  }

export default Divider;
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @soutot, thanks for your suggestion. But I really want to know for future use cases that how do I assign default values to my props. Like if I have `<Text>Hello {this.props.something}</Text>` and I don't assign `something` a value where I use my component it still says "world" for example.

Comment: I updated the answer. Take it as an example and check if works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
export default class Divider extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <View style = {{
    height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    marginTop: {this.props.marginTop},
    marginBottom: {this.props.marginBottom},
    backgroundColor: {this.props.backgroundColor},
   }} />
  );
 }
}

Divider.defaultProps = {
  marginTop: 0,
  marginBottom: 8,
  backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF80",
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohadmed Khalil, unfortunately this doesn't work for me. :/